# Custom Sort in Excel by Specific Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

First, I've searched, but if I missed the answer to this, my apologies.

I'm trying to sort a column by a number contained in parentheses. For example, I would like to sort the following Column A to look like Column B.

(Okay, so no images without enough rep)

Column A

First LastName (1)

First LastName (1)

First LastName (3)

First LastName (1)

First LastName (1)

First LastName (14)

First LastName (1)

First LastName (21)

First LastName (1)

Column B

First LastName (21)

First LastName (14)

First LastName (3)

First LastName (1)

First LastName (1)

...and so on.

Thank you for your help!

Could someone provide a step-by-step on how to do that? Assuming it's doable. I'm using '07, but I do have '16 as well, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

To sort by a part of a value in a column, you first need to get the part you want to sort on into its own column.  Assuming that there are no parentheses in FirstName or Lastname, this is easy.  I'm going to give you the steps in separate columns, though they could easily be combined.  Note also, that in the following steps, we're in row 1.

1. In column B, find the location of the left parenthesis with the FIND function, specifically

   `=FIND("(",$A1)`

In your example -- "Firstname Lastname (21)"  -- this would evaluate to 20, since the left parenthesis is the 20th character.

2. In column C, find the location of the right parenthesis with

   `=FIND(")",$A1)`
3. Now use the MID function to pull out the contents of the parentheses. The MID function returns a specific number of characters from a text string starting at the position you specify.  If you aren't used to thinking about working with text strings, pause to consider (a) that you'll want to start one character to the right of the left parenthesis (*i.e.* one plus the value you calculated in column B, and (b) the number of characters you want to pull out is equal to one *less* than C - B. So Column D will read

   `=MID($A1,$B1+1,$C1-$B1-1)`
4. If you actually try to sort on column D, you'll soon see that numbers aren't sorting the way you expect.  This is because Excel still sees them as text strings and is therefore views "100" as comoing before "21"  So in column E, wrap column D in a function (NUMBERVALUE) that turns text into number, like so:

   `=NUMBERVALUE($D2)`

You can now sort on column E.  (Obviously, you could combine any or all of the above steps into a single step.  If it were me, I'd probably keep the two FINDs in their own colunns (B and C) but combine the last two steps as

```
`=NUMBERVALUE(MID($A1,$B1+1,$C1-$B1-1))`
```

Note that I'm reading your question to mean that you want to sort by the number in parenthesis even if the names are different.  In other words, regardless if the Firstname Lastname is Abigail Adams or Zev Zeebra, you want the one followed by (21) to come before the one followed by (10).  If that's not the case you can use similar technique (probably using the "LEFT" function rather than "MID" to create a separate column with the names only.  Then sort on that first and then the column produced above.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extract the number into a new column, then sort the data by that column.

```
=MID(A2,FIND("(",A2),5)
```

If your numbers have more than 4 digits, change the 5 to a larger value.

For a start, this formula will return the number in brackets, like `(14)`. We need to remove the brackets, anyway, so we might as well return just `14)` without the opening bracket. That can be done with

```
=MID(A2,FIND("(",A2)+1,5)
```

Now we can remove the closing bracket by substituting it with an empty text `""`.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("(",A2)+1,5),")","")
```

The result is `14` and it looks like a number, but it is text. We need to convert it to a number with the Value function:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("(",A2)+1,5),")",""))
```

Copy that formula down, then sort by the column with the formula.

[image]